# In multi threading a thread has acquired lock on object? Does this mean lock on all objects of that class?

Tags: java, multithreading

I mean if a thread has lock on an object of some class say A.
What if another thread creates another instance of A and tries to access it??

I don't know my question itself is valid??
please understand my question
If not?
Correct my question even if it is possible??

Comment: Multithreading and locking are complicated, you need to follow a few tutorials and play around with it. No, you only have a lock on the instance, not any other instance nor all instances of the class.

Comment: What do you mean "has lock on object...?" Do you mean that some thread `t` is executing in a `synchronized(o){...}` block? That does _not_ prevent other threads from _accessing_ the object `o`. It only delays other threads that are trying to enter a similar `synchronized(o)` block until after thread `t` has left the block. If you want to prevent other threads from accessing the object, then it is _your_ responsibility to ensure that the only accesses happen inside `synchronized` blocks.

Comment: ```another instance of A ```  means another lock. It has nothing to do with the previous lock.

Answer (score 0):

> In multi threading a thread has acquired lock on object? Does this mean lock on all objects of that class?

A thread acquires a lock on *an object* and any other objects instances (either of the same class or others) are not affected by the lock.   It would be easy to write a test case for this:

```
synchronized (new Object()) {
    System.out.println("in lock for Object #1");
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (new Object()) {
                System.out.println("in lock for Object #2");
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    thread.join();
}
```

Even though one `Object` instance is locked doesn't mean that another lock on a different object instance can't happen in parallel.  Locking on the same object *instance* in both cases would have caused a deadlock.